# html background image appears correct on desktop browser, not on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I have background images for fixed position menu items.
They appear correct on a desktop browser, but they become stretched and only show the center portion of the image when displayed on a mobile browser, and the image appears to be approx 4x original size.

I've attempted setting background-size:cover cover !important; to force the size to fill the container, but that has also had no effect.

I know there are issues with using fixed positioning and the viewport on mobile, but I've tried setting the elements to relative positioning with no effect.

HTML:
head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

menu:

```
<ul id="shortcuts" role="complementary" class="children-tooltip tooltip-right lulus">
<li class="current"><a href="/Home" class="shortcut-dashboard" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/Calendar" class="shortcut-agenda" title="Events">Events</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
#shortcuts {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 998;
top: 44px;
left: 10px;
margin: 0;
width: 240px;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 15px 4px 5px 14px;
*padding-bottom: 25px;
border: 1px solid white;
background: #d9d9d9 url(../img/old-browsers/style/bg_shortcuts.png) repeat-x;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(white), to(#d9d9d9));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient( white, #d9d9d9 );
background: -moz-linear-gradient( white, #d9d9d9 );
background: -ms-linear-gradient( white, #d9d9d9 );
background: -o-linear-gradient( white, #d9d9d9 );
background: linear-gradient( white, #d9d9d9 );
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#shortcuts > li {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    margin: -5px 10px 25px 0;
    }
.shortcut-dashboard { margin-left:0px !important; /*padding-bottom:65px; width:70px !important;*/ background-image: url(../img/standard/icons/Home_Icon.png) !important; background-position:center center !important; background-size:cover cover !important; }
.shortcut-agenda { margin-left:0px !important; /*padding-bottom:65px; width:70px !important;*/ background-image: url(../img/standard/icons/Calendar_Icon.png) !important; background-position:center center !important; }
```

I can't figure out why the background image is getting stretched and only on mobile browsers. This is the only place my background images are behaving badly. Any help would be nice... I'm not opposed to corporal punishment on these misbehaving children!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from "The Definitive Guide To HTML/XHTML 6th Edition":

"HTML and XHTML documents can wind up in the strangest places these days, such
as on cellular phones. To help the browser figure out the best way to render your documents,
include the media attribute within the  tag. The value of this attribute is
the document’s intended medium, although it doesn’t preclude rendering by other
media. The default value is screen (computer display). Other values include tty (text
only), tv (television), projection (theaters), handheld (PDAs and cell phones), print
(ink on paper), braille (tactile devices), embossed (Braille printers), aural (audio;
speech synthesis, for instance), and all (many different types of media).
If you want to explicitly list several types of media, instead of specifying all, use a
quote-enclosed, comma-separated list of media types as the value of the media
attribute. For example:

tells the browser that your document contains CSS both for printing and for computer
displays.
Be careful specifying media, because the browser cannot apply the styles you define
unless the document is being rendered on one of your specified media. Thus, the
browser would not apply our example set of styles designed for media="screen,print"
if the user is, for instance, connected to the Web with a handheld computer.
How do you create different style definitions for different media without creating
multiple copies of your document? The CSS2 standard lets you define media-specific
stylesheets through its extension to the @import at-rule and through the @media atrule,
which we describe in section 8.1.5 later in this chapter."

PS, try to make your code more relative: instead of using 'px', specify the value in percentage.

Comment: I'm already handling various media sizes:
<!-- For all browsers -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css?v=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/css/print.css?v=1">
 <!-- For progressively larger displays -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only all and (min-width: 480px)" href="/css/480.css?v=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only all and (min-width: 768px)" href="/css/768.css?v=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only all and (min-width: 992px)" href="/css/992.css?v=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only all and (min-width: 1200px)" href="/css/1200.css?v=1">

Comment: You didn't mention that in the source code you provided.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/mobile/making-your-website-mobile-part-3.html#fbid=HyxQaAkOXhR

Comment: For simplicity's sake, I only mentioned what I felt was relevant to my particular issue. Again, this problem is isolated to this menu only. All other background images, containers, etc. appear correct on the site.

Answer (score 0):

My bad on this one, folks. I had a CSS file that was overriding the background-size to a predetermined pixel size. I removed this property from the CSS file and all is well.

On a side note, does anyone know of any apps or plugins that allow me to view the CSS of a page from a mobile browser? Something similar to built in desktop browsers' developer toolbar? This would have saved me a lot of headache...